# Mysql How to check new data reqularly without cron?

Tags: php, mysql

I have Db A and B, both of them are mysql 5.6.

An external application insert new data to multiple tables in db A. Using trigger, I insert new data from A to my table in db B realtime.

How can I give realtime alert if there is new data are inserted to my db B ?

Now I using php cronjob to check it reqularly.

Any idea? Btw, it’s better if its using PHP too.

Comment: Not possible triggers don't give insert signals.

Comment: use additional column in A & B with different default values, according to column value you can check

Comment: so the answer is still checking using cron?

Comment: When A inserts into B then you could also populate a notifications table which is checked via CRON job and alert yourself every minute or whatever.